# SSIS Odata VSTS WIQL An error occured while retrieving the metadata

Tags: ssis, odata, azure-devops, wiql

My project currently uses an SSIS to get data from VSTS. We use an Odata source to get a particular collection, eg WorkItems. That works fine.

What I want to do, but can't figure out how to, is to retrieve the results from a saved query within VSTS. What I've tried is copying the url from the VSTS website into the Odata's Source Editor under "query options". I get data back when I hit the preview button but when I try to save or see Columns I get the message: "An error occurred while retrieving the metadata". Does anyone know what's going on or could give me a suggestion?

If that doesn't work is there a way I could use WIQL to query VSTS? If I could do that from SSIS, or anything else, that would solve my problem as well.

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Comment: hello, i have read your question and i saw thta Odata is working fine from SSIS i have an error to get data from Odata : there is no connexion name "connexion" found

Answer (score 0):

Using VSTS REST API instead.

Also, the REST API supports WIQL: [Wiql - Query By Wiql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/wiql/query%20by%20wiql)